# Unable to deploy Google Cloud Datalab on an existing project due to RPC failure

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I would like to deploy Google Cloud Datalab as a module on an existing project. I have successfully deployed datalab on a small demo project, but the deploy is failing with our large scale application (the project is based in the US, I am deploying with our owner account, we have the relevant apis enable, etc).

The specific point of failure does not match what I have seen in other datalab deploy failures on SO. The deploy script fails when attempting to create a datalab branch in our repository (see log output below). Interestingly, I have repeated the deploy process multiple times and repeatedly see the RPC failure on file 27/35.

Worth noting that the cloud repo for this project is linked to an external github repo.

Any ideas on what is going on here or how to fix? Thanks!

```
Dec  6 01:50:28 datalab-deploy-main-20151206-01-49-46 startupscript:  create mode 100644 datalab/tutorials/Storage/Storage APIs.ipynb

Dec  6 01:50:28 datalab-deploy-main-20151206-01-49-46 startupscript:  create mode 100644 datalab/tutorials/Storage/Storage Commands.ipynb

Dec  6 01:50:33 datalab-deploy-main-20151206-01-49-46 startupscript: remote: Storing objects: 77% (27/35)#033[K#015error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200

Dec  6 01:50:33 datalab-deploy-main-20151206-01-49-46 startupscript: remote: Storing objects: 91% (32/35)#033[K#015remote: Storing objects: 97% (34/35)#033[K#015remote: Storing objects: 100% (35/35)#033[K#015remote: Storing objects: 100% (35/35), done.#033[K

Dec  6 01:50:33 datalab-deploy-main-20151206-01-49-46 startupscript: remote: Processing commits: 100% (1/1)#033[K#015remote: Processing commits: 100% (1/1), done.#033[K

Dec  6 01:50:33 datalab-deploy-main-20151206-01-49-46 startupscript: remote: Error: internal server error#033[K

Dec  6 01:50:33 datalab-deploy-main-20151206-01-49-46 startupscript: fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Dec  6 01:50:33 datalab-deploy-main-20151206-01-49-46 startupscript: fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Dec  6 01:50:33 datalab-deploy-main-20151206-01-49-46 startupscript: Everything up-to-date

Dec  6 01:50:33 datalab-deploy-main-20151206-01-49-46 startupscript: Step creating datalab branch failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same problem except our repository was mirrored from bitbucket. In our case, creating `datalab` branch on <strike>bitbucket</strike> **cloud repository** solved the problem.